# how to convert a RDD to other RDD using case class property?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have an RDD as below with name: **other_nodes**:

```
(4,(1,true))
(22,(1,true))
(14,(1,true))
(3,(1,true))
(8,(1,true))
(18,(1,true))
```

i wrote a case class as below and applyed it on a graph and it gave the result i wanted:

```
case class nodes_properties(label:Int, isVisited:Boolean=false)
```

when i apply case on a graph its result looks like this:

```
(1,nodes_properties(15,false))
(2,nodes_properties(11,false))
(3,nodes_properties(9,false))
```

**Problem:** how can i apply the case class i have defined, on the **other_nodes** RDD to get the result like as below:

```
(4,nodes_properties(1,true))
(22,nodes_properties(1,true))
(14,nodes_properties(1,true))
(3,nodes_properties(1,true))
(8,nodes_properties(1,true))
(18,nodes_properties(1,true))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution might work:

```
scala> val data = sc.parallelize(Seq((4,(1, true)),(22,(1,true))))
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (Int, Boolean))] = ParallelCollectionRDD[72] at parallelize at <console>:39

scala> data.take(2)
res27: Array[(Int, (Int, Boolean))] = Array((4,(1,true)), (22,(1,true)))

scala> val data1 = data.map(elem => (elem._1, nodes_properties(elem._2._1, elem._2._2)))
data1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, nodes_properties)] = MapPartitionsRDD[73] at map at <console>:42

scala> data1.take(2)
res28: Array[(Int, nodes_properties)] = Array((4,nodes_properties(1,true)), (22,nodes_properties(1,true)))
```

**EDIT**

The problem is each element in `others_rdd` is of Type `(VertexId, Any)`. You need to convert to `(VertexId, (Int, Boolean))` type in order for your case class to apply. The way to do is

```
val newRdd = others_rdd.map(elem => (elem._1, elem._2.asInstanceOf[(Int,Boolean)]))
```

After performing this, you can apply the solution as shown above by mapping to `node_properties` class.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: thank you for your reply. i think you mentioned the exact way. but there is a little problem. i dont know why in  ```data.map(elem => (elem._1, nodes_properties(elem._2._1, elem._2._2)))```   ```elem._2._1```  and  ```elem._2._2```  gives error.  my RDD's class is: ```class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD```

Comment: Can you tell me the type when you do `others_rdd.take(1)`?

Comment: i use intellij and it shows the type as:  ``` val x: Array[(VertexId, Any)] =other_RDD.take(1) ```  and when i do ```println(x.getClass)``` the result is ```class [Lscala.Tuple2;```

Comment: i do some join and mapvalues operations and at the end the ```other_rdd``` is the result of them

Comment: when i use ```other_rdd.getClass``` the result is ```class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD ``` and intellij shows the type for ```other_rdd``` as  ```RDD[(VertexId, Any)]```

Comment: I have updated the solution. Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: thank you so much. i am really thankful from you for solving my problem .i was really confused about that. thanks.

Comment: No Problem.Happy to help!!

Comment: Mr. Anand Sai (@ Anand Sai) is it possible for you to have a look at my new question? i have done an experiment today and i faced with a new problem. this is the link for the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547724/what-is-best-structure-to-choose-for-updaing-nodes-property-in-spark-graphx